# How to add a site to Yandex which is hosted in Azure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service, yandex

Web Site is running on Azure (Cloud Service). To be indexed by Yandex I need to place the html file below in the root directory.

```
<html>
    <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></head>
    <body>Verification: 123456d0a12</body>
</html>
```

It doesn't work like ordinary web server's "www" folder. Anybody has a clue?

I located the file under "Azure.Service\bin\Release\app.publish\Azure.Service.cspkg". Tried to open it. Looks like:

[image]

Little more help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the yandex_123456d0a12.html file in your Service Package (cspkg) file for it to be deployed with your Web Role (in a Cloud Service).

Other options for validating Yandex are listed here: http://api.yandex.com/webmaster/doc/dg/reference/hosts-type.xml. If you don't want to redeploy the application it might be easier for you to add a TXT record (DNS level). This doesn't require you to redeploy the application.